# Heroku's db:pull/push seems to ignore sequences?

Tags: heroku, playframework, sequences

I've been messing around with the new Play framework 2.0 for a possible petproject. After deploying a testapplication to Heroku I wanted to perform some checks to see how I can manage my data which will be stored into Heroku's postgresql database.

I stumbled upon the db:pull and db:push command. Apparently it should be easy to take a dump of my development environment's db and overwrite the database of my production environment (and the other way around) with it. However while testing I noticed that it seems to ignore my SEQUENCES? Is it supposed to only copy the tables and their data? My schema is looking like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE task_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE task (
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('task_id_seq'),
label varchar(255)
);
```

So my 'task_id_seq'-SEQUENCE is not being extracted for some reason. I tried it both from prod to dev and the other way around and they both leave out my SEQUENCES.
I hope that I'm overlooking something...?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I tried out pgbackups to produce and place dumps instead, and it's working flawlessly.